# CP210x driver on debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, drivers

I'm trying to get the Columbus P-7 Pro unit working on a Debian 11 VM, the readme notes are the following

Build instructions for Ubuntu:

```
make # (your cp210x driver)
cp cp210x.ko to /lib/modules//kernel/drivers/usb/serial
insmod /lib/modules/<kernel-version/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
insmod cp210x.ko
```

I ran `lsmod` and couldn't see this driver, the documentation only has instructions for Ubuntu so I'm unsure if there's anything I can do to get this device communicating. Currently I'm not getting anything from it despite trying a range of options with `gpsd`.

There is a file in the package I have called `cp210x.c`, is this the driver that I can copy into a place within the Debian system? I'm unsure how easy it is if this was all designed for Ubuntu however switching the OS would be very difficult for this application.

Answer (score 1):

The `cp210x` driver is shipped as part of the Debian kernels, you should be able to load it by running

```
sudo modprobe cp210x
```

without needing to build or install anything.